# Large python data object

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to store and access data that consists of X, Y pairs, where X is a 32 char string representing a hexadecimal number and Y is a float32 in range of 0 to 100. The operations I would like to execute:

1. Add new X, Y pairs over ~10,000,000 iterations
2. Get X, Y pairs with highest Y
3. Access Y for a given X
4. Change Y for a given X

The straightforward way to implement such an object would be using dictionaries, but I am not sure how efficient that would be.

What would be an efficient way to implement such an object with respect to memory consumption and execution time?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you loading your pairs from a file or are you generating them 1 by 1 ?

Comment: I am generating them 1 by 1 iteratively (part of a large-scale process)

Comment: Then you can store the current maximum and it's ID. When you generate a new sequence, just check if Y is higher than the current max. If not, change nothing, else, update your current max and it's ID. Doing so, you won't have any issue related to your data structure

Comment: As for (2), I agree that having a separate object that will be compared to every new entry might be helpful. My main concern is memory consumption for holding such an object and execution time of (1), (3), and (4). I am not sure that a simple dictionary is the perfect object for this task.